# Are there Kabbalistic sources that address abnormal sensitivity to smell?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, smell

A friend married a woman who has an auto-immune disease called Hashimoto's. It effects your hyperthyroid and hypothyroid. One of the troubling aspects to her condition is a high-sensitivity to chemicals. She cannot use common household cleaners, wear perfume, and even hand soaps give her bad headaches within minutes. It has not been easy, but they have managed.

In their travels they visited a community where, ironically, 3 other women attended also had this issue at varying degrees (one of which was debilitated for weeks with too much exposure). The shul purchased machines that neutralized the effects of chemicals (such as perfume and cologne) in the room.

While some write it off as 'mental' and others a 'legitimate auto-immune issue', I am curious if there are kabbalistic sources that support a more spiritual element to this discussion?

I heard of a story of a man eating a goose and when the rabbi looked at him he saw a goose (Sifran Shel Tzaddikim, p.68 as quoted Jewish Spiritual Practices, Buxbaum). So if what you eat 'changes' how you're perceived, can your thoughts give off a scent?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the source for this, but I heard Rav Buta from Israel (Rav Ovadia Yosefs Chazan for 18 years) say that a the more sensitive a persons smell is, the more spirituially clean/pure that person is. its a sign of the sensitivity of that persons spirit. This was said in praise of Rav Ovadia Zatzal who had a very sensitive sense of smell.

Comment: Interesting. I don't recall reading that in Artscroll's biography of R' Ovadia ztl

Comment: @Re'eh Why would the biography of a posek and leader mention his sense of smell?

Comment: @mevaqesh Touche. I guess I assumed if it's about him - especially something unique like a 'sensitivity' - it would be mentioned.